# cout vs printf in C++ giving different output

Tags: c++, printf, stdin, cout

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <stdio.h>
    using namespace std ;

    int main(){        
      string name ;
    float salary ;
    float made ;

    cin >> name ;
    cin >> salary ;
    cin >> made ;

    float result = salary + 0.15*made ; 
    cout<<"TOTAL = R$ "<<setprecision(2)<<result <<endl ;
    printf("TOTAL = R$ %.2f\n", result) ;

}
```

Input:
Jack
500.00
1230.00

---

Output:

TOTAL = R$ 6.8e+002

---

TOTAL = R$ 684.50

the right output should be 684.50. Why does it produce different output? I want to know how cout works in comparison with printf

Comment: You need fixed: cout<<"TOTAL = R$ "<<fixed << setprecision(2)<<result <<endl ;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`500 + 1230 * 0.15` gives you `684.5`, hence the `cout` is still correct, since you've only allowed two digits of precision, the `6` and the `8`.

If you want the `cout` version to be of the same format as the `printf`, you need to use `fixed`:

```
cout << "TOTAL = R$ " << fixed << setprecision(2) << result << endl ;
```

Changing your code to use *that* line instead of your current one gives:

```
TOTAL = R$ 684.50
TOTAL = R$ 684.50
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, `ostream` formats floating point using the `%g`
format specifier.  You need to tell it to use `%f`, with either:

```
std::cout.setf( std::ios_base::fixed, std::ios_base::floatfield );
```

or

```
std::cout << std::fixed;
```

A better solution is usually to defined application specific
manipulators, so that you don't specify the physical aspects of
formatting, but rather the logic ones, and that a change in
the format of some logical entity can be done in a single
location.  Thus, you might define:

```
std::ostream&
salary( std::ostream& dest )
{
    dest.setf( std::ios_base::fixed, std::ios_base::floatfield );
    dest.precision( 2 );
    return dest;
}
```

And then write:

```
std::cout << "TOTAL =- R$ " << salary << result << std::endl;
```

It's also possible to make the manipulators classes, with
a destructor which restores the original formatting state.

Answer (score 1):

Set precision changes the number of significant numbers hence you have two of them (68).

What you need is fixed point format which is set by the `setiosflags(ios::fixed)`.

Correct code would be:

```
cout << "TOTAL = R$ " << setiosflags(ios::fixed) << setprecision(2) << result << endl;
```

More on this in the [guide on output formatting](http://www.arachnoid.com/cpptutor/student3.html).

Comment: I don't think `std::setiosflags` is defined if you pass it `ios::fixed`.  At any rate, it won't work correctly.

Comment: Why would not it work correctly? I have tested it and it does provide the exactly asked output...

Comment: With which compiler?  Or maybe you didn't actually test it thoroughly enough: it doesn't work with VC++, nor with g++.  Try setting `ios_base::fixed`, then `ios_base::scientific`, then `ios_base::fixed` again.

Comment: And just for the record, the page you link to is incorrect across the board.  Don't use it; it's bad.